# Chatbot query 90% correct

Tags: php, mysql, sql, chatbot

We have a chatbot with a couple of queries and answers. However, when a user asks a question, the question needs to be exactly as in the database.

```
$check_data = "SELECT antwoord FROM Chatbot WHERE vraag LIKE '%$getMesg%'";
```

Is there an option that the user's question can be, for example, 90% be the same as in the query.

Comment: Create your custom function which will calculate this similarity, and apply it.

Comment: I don't even know what "90% the same" means.  Does that mean that if the user asks for 9*10, then 100 is an appropriate answer?

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for natural language processing